# Media won't instantiate despite correct import packages in java

Tags: java, plugins, media, instantiation

my Media object does not want to instantiate and i have all the correct imported jar files including JavaFX so that I can play mp3 files.

I have the imported packages:

```
import javax.media.*
import com.sun.media.MediaPlayer;
import com.sun.media.codec.audio.mp3.*
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Media;
```

But it still doesn't run. Any suggestions would be appreciated as i've been googling everyting about media and plugins for days now :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must import this packages:

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
```

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/Playmp3file.htm) is example of mp3 player.

Comment: hi, thank you for responding. The problem i'm having is that i cannot import javafx.scene.media.Media. I can actually import javafx.scene.media only and import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer; Do you know why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete com.sun.media.mediaPlayer;

I had the same problem just now xD. Hope this helps.